# How to install python packages in cmd?

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, module, pip, installation-package

I have been trying to install some packages from last two days. But I couldn't able to succeed in that. The only error I am getting, when I tried to install packages through pip in cmd is :

```
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 405 Method Not Allowed',))': /simple/numpy/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for numpy
```

I tried to find the solution on different platform, but I couldn't succeed in that.
I am using company network. Might be that is the problem, but I am not sure.

Could anyone help me with this?From last two days, I am sick of it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide errors, please.

Comment: Are you trying - pip install  numpy?

Comment: @Dmitry, ya C:\>pip install pandas or numpy

Comment: Could you please check the documentation - https://scipy.org/install.html

Comment: @Dmitry, may I know what does user means here?....User = saralap or anything else?

Comment: I used pipenv and that command - pipenv install numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose. It's work fine. I checked.

Comment: The command install pip install --user pipenv

Comment: It is not working!, still same error

Comment: Check please - https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-packages-for-your-project

Comment: I installed through whl. But I need to install pyro4. So Pyro4 is not installing. I don't know why?. Could you sahre location to download pyro4 file for python 3.6? I also installed torch and numpy. But no pyro4

Answer (score 0):

It's most definitely your company network. A viable solution would be to run:

```
export http_proxy=company-proxy:8000
export https_proxy=company-proxy:8000
```

After that confirm you have outgoing network:

```
curl https://www.google.com/
```

> The above should display a long html output.

For this to work you'll have to ask the systems admin for a proxy you can use.

Comment: It is working, but I couldn't able to install pyro4 package. I installed the package through wheel. But I did the same thing for pyro4, again same error. any idea why?

Comment: I would need more information about the error you get, the exact way you tried to install it and the setup of your machine.